# How to compile an existing .9.patch and save it to storage programmatically?

Tags: java, android, compilation, encode, nine-patch

How can i compile an existing .9.png file from the asset folder and save it to external storage?

I'm asking if i can remove the black lines programmatically and save the result in the storage.

Comment: AFAIK, nine-patch PNG files are only useful when they are drawable resources. Neither assets nor files on the filesystem would work.

Comment: @CommonsWare I know but I'm making a theme maker app for Android and the themes need a compiled version of the .9.png i know that aapt does this when Android studio compiles the APK file. I want to do the compiling of the nine patch drawable inside the app